# Multiindex instead of groupby

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm digging a little deeper in to pandas multi-indexing and i'm wondering if I can replace groupby iterative processing with multi-indexing.

currently I use this function

raw data:

```
                       station_name station_code breaktype
0                               ABC         ABC1         N
1                   American Heroes         HERO         L
2                   American Heroes         HERO         N
3           American Movie Classics          AMC         L
4           American Movie Classics          AMC         N
5                     Animal Planet         ANPL         L
6                     Animal Planet         ANPL         N
```

Currently I use this function:

```
def createRegexPattern(df):
    df = df.copy()
    groups = df.groupby(["station_name", "station_code"])
    patterns = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["origional_index", "root_words", "pattern"])
    for key, group in groups:
        patterns = patterns.append(pd.DataFrame(
            {"origional_index": [group.index.to_list()], 
             "root_words": [key], 
             "pattern": [tuple(functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x + re.split('[\s,-]',y.strip()), key,[]))]}
        ))
    return patterns.reset_index(drop=True)
```

To produce this:

```
   origional_index                             root_words                                  pattern
0              [0]                            (ABC, ABC1)                              (ABC, ABC1)
1           [1, 2]                (American Heroes, HERO)                 (American, Heroes, HERO)
2           [3, 4]         (American Movie Classics, AMC)         (American, Movie, Classics, AMC)
3           [5, 6]                  (Animal Planet, ANPL)                   (Animal, Planet, ANPL)
```

could I use multi-indexing instead to produce a result like:
desired result of multi-indexing

```
                                                                                origional_index breaktype
    station_name                   station_code  pattern
0   ABC                            ABC1          (ABC, ABC1)                                    0         N
1   American Heroes                HERO          (American, Heroes, HERO)                       1         L
                                                                                                2         N
2   American Movie Classics        AMC           (American, Movie, Classics, AMC)               3         L
                                                                                                4         N
3   Animal Planet                  ANPL          (Animal, Planet, ANPL)                         5         L
                                                                                                6         N
```

Is this a viable use for the DataFrame, or should I stop while I'm ahead...

Answer (score 0):

You can get something like that pretty trivially with `.set_index`:

```
In [64]: df.reset_index().set_index(["station_name", "station_code"])
Out[64]:
                                      index breaktype
station_name            station_code
ABC                     ABC1              0         N
American Heroes         HERO              1         L
                        HERO              2         N
American Movie Classics AMC               3         L
                        AMC               4         N
Animal Planet           ANPL              5         L
                        ANPL              6         N
```

You could also do something like turn `breaktype` into columns with the original index as a label, and then calculate your tokens off of the combined index:

```
In [65]: df.reset_index().set_index(["station_name", "station_code", "breaktype"]).unstack()['index']
Out[65]:
breaktype                               L    N
station_name            station_code
ABC                     ABC1          NaN  0.0
American Heroes         HERO          1.0  2.0
American Movie Classics AMC           3.0  4.0
Animal Planet           ANPL          5.0  6.0
```

I don't know that either of these are actually "better" than your `.groupby` method though.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create your `pattern` column up-front and then use `set_index()` to achieve your desired output:

```
df['pattern'] = (df['station_name'].str.split() + df['station_code'].str.split()).apply(tuple).astype(str)

df.reset_index().set_index(['station_name','station_code','pattern']).rename(columns={'index': 'original_index'})
```

Yields:

```
                                                                               original_index breaktype
station_name            station_code pattern                                                           
ABC                     ABC1         ('ABC', 'ABC1')                                        0         N
American Heroes         HERO         ('American', 'Heroes', 'HERO')                         1         L
                                     ('American', 'Heroes', 'HERO')                         2         N
American Movie Classics AMC          ('American', 'Movie', 'Classics', 'AMC')               3         L
                                     ('American', 'Movie', 'Classics', 'AMC')               4         N
Animal Planet           ANPL         ('Animal', 'Planet', 'ANPL')                           5         L
                                     ('Animal', 'Planet', 'ANPL')                           6         N
```